# URL in $.post with multiples websites

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

I have a JavaScript to fill my address

```
  $.post('/Endereco/getEnderecos', { CardCode: dado }, function (data) {
    if (data) {
  (...)
```

My problem is: if i publish my website in 'localhost',works,but if i publish my website in "localhost/site" not work, is the same to "www.mydomain.com" and "www.mydomain.com/site"

My website is Development in C# asp.net MVC3 IIS7

i have tried use the javascript to get the host, but not work

Thanks

Comment: Is it the same when you remove leading slash from url? Endereco/getEnderecos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a leading slash in your address `/Endereco/getEnderecos`, this will cause the browser to navigate to the root of the current host and then the URL you have provided.

For example, posting to `/somePage` from a page at `www.mysite.com/folder/subfolder/page` will post to the url `www.mysite.com/somePage`.

To rectify this, remove the slash from before `Endereco`, so your `post` looks like this:

```
$.post('Endereco/getEnderecos', { CardCode: dado }, function (data) {
  if (data) {
(...)
```

In response to your comment, you could instead use the `..` notation which means "go up a folder":

```
$.post('../../Endereco/getEnderecos', { CardCode: dado }, function (data) {
  if (data) {
(...)
```

From `localhost/order/Endereco/getEnderecos` your resulting URL would be `localhost/Endereco/getEnderecos`, as we used two `..` components, it has gone up two folders instead of one.

I was looking for some kind of tutorial on relative URLs and found this page: http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html. It might help you to better understand HTTP URLs =]

Comment: If I do that my link is thus: "localhost/order/endereco/getEnderecos" but my function is in "localhost/endereco/getEnderecos"
i have not tried in localhost/site yet

Comment: See my edit, I've included the `..` notation and a link to a page which I found that might help you to further your understanding of relative URLs.

Comment: hmmm... i understand but don't have a way to make this dynamically?
To work in any site
ex:
www.somesite.com
www.somesite.com/site
www.somesite.com/site/website
(...)

Comment: Well, as long as you know how many levels back up you need to go, it will work. So as long as your folder structure remains the same, you'll be ok.